# Defining Functions Without the Use of Algebraic Expressions

Tags: functions

This is a question out of curiosity.

Usually, functions are defined this way: $f(x) = x^2 + 3$, right?

Could I, say, define a function, calling it $f(x)$ again, that takes in a value $x$, moves a point through the perimeter of a specific shape--a shape that is cyclic, and its endpoint meets its starting point-- $x$ units and outputs the x-axis distance the point is from the origin? Could I also define another function, $h(x)$ for example, that, instead of outputting the $x$ distance from the origin, outputs the $y$ distance from the origin?

I see this close to how the trigonometric functions are defined, where there inputs could be of different units of measurements.

I do realize my question could be a little bit vague, and I could provide an example of how it theoretically would work.

If I couldn't define such function this way, why not? Aren't the trigonometric functions defined in a very similar manner where the input is not plugged in an algebraic expression? Basically, can I define a function without relying on algebraic expressions?

Comment: In one word, yes. Have you read and understood the Wikipedia article [Function (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics))?

Comment: I didn't read it yet. I guess I'll have to get into the habit of reading articles then. Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 1):

Given sets $A, B$, intuitively a function $f: A\to B$ is well-defined if for all $x\in A$, you $\textbf{can find}^{(1)}$ a $\textbf{unique}^{(2)}$ $f(x)$ and $\textbf{you obtain the same $f(x)$ regardless of how you express $x$}^{(3)}$. That makes three conditions worth checking. You can find the formal definition on the wiki page commented above.

Examples of some $\textbf{non}$-well-defined functions:

$f: \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Z$ mapping $f(\frac n m) = n$ is not well defined.  Clearly $\frac 1 2 = \frac 2 4$ yet $f(\frac 1 2) = 1 \neq f(\frac 2 4) = 2$. (3rd condition is broken.)

$f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ mapping $x$ to $f(x)$ such $f(x)^2 = x$ is not well-defined.  There is no $f(-1) \in \mathbb R$ such $f(-1)^2 = -1$. (1st condition is broken.)

$f: \mathbb R_+=\left\{\text{positive real numbers}\right\} \to \mathbb R$ mapping $x$ to $f(x)$ such $f(x)^2 = x$ is not well-defined either. $2^2 = (-2)^2 = 4$ so you could have both $f(4) = 2$ and $f(4) = -2$. (2nd condition is broken.)

$f: \mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R_+$ mapping $x$ to $f(x)$ such $f(x)^2 = x$ is well-defined (you may check why). As you can see the description of your 'function' only does part of the work, a good choice of domain and codomain can make or break a 'function'.

$f: \mathbb R^2 = \left\{\text{points $(x,y)$ on the plane}\right\} \to \mathbb R^2$ mapping $(x,y)$ to the point $f((x,y))$ of the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ closest to $(x,y)$ is not well-defined. All points of the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ are the same $1$ distance away from $(0,0)$, so you can't uniquely decide the value of $f((0,0))$. It could be $f((0,0)) = (0,1)$ as well as $f((0,0)) = (1,0)$. (2nd condition is broken.)

$f: \mathbb R^2 \setminus \left\{(0,0)\right\}\to \mathbb R^2$ mapping $(x,y)$ to the point $f((x,y))$ of the unit circle $x^2+y^2 = 1$ closest to $(x,y)$ is however well-defined (you may check why).